# confusing wpa_supplicant processes while trying to use dbus api

Tags: raspbian-buster, wpa-supplicant, dbus

I am trying to write some code that is to use dbus api to access wpa_supplicant. My understanding from reading various posts that wpa_supplicant must be started with `-u` flag to fully expose it's apis to dbus. So I edited, `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` to by adding the `-u` flag to the invocation of the `wpa_supplicant` daemon in the `wpa_supplicant_start()`.

At this point I couldn't use wpa_cli to connect to `wlan0` anymore. I checked the processes with `ps` and got,

```
pi@raspi:~ $ ps -aux | grep wpa_sup
root       306  0.0  1.0  10724  4732 ?        Ss   21:21   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
```

So, I edited `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` again to remove `-u` flag, rebooted etc. and again checked the processes. This time I got,

```
pi@raspi:~ $ ps -aux | grep wpa_sup
root       260  0.3  1.0  10724  4640 ?        Ss   21:25   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       350  0.1  0.9  10988  4052 ?        Ss   21:25   0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

and now I can use wpa_cli to connect to `wlan0`.

This is confusing to me, I would greatly appreciate some explanation that would help me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, it appears that `wpa_supplicant.service` should be disabled as it was preventing `wpa_cli` from connecting to `wlan0`.

After doing,

```bsh
sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant
sudo reboot
```

I was able to connect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the case. My system has both `dhcpcd` (which starts `wpa_supplicant -iwlan0`) and `wpa_supplicant` (which starts `wpa_supplicant -u`) services enabled.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev any ideas why is this happening in mine? I am using pi zero. Why does `dhcpcd` not like `-u` in my case? That's the only thing I changed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I will be able to help. I'm not actively using WiFi in the first place. However, my understanding is that `wpa_cli` is not using DBus at all, it connects via a socket.